# WebClient create java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults

Tags: spring, webclient, webflux

I'm trying to play around Spring WebFlux Webclient.
Tried to create a simple webclient in a quartz cron job

`this.webClient = WebClient.create(this.queryUrl);`

I made sure the queryUrl is valid.

However, I've got an error as following:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults(ExchangeStrategies.java:67)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.initExchangeStrategies(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:302)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.build(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:269)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:154)
```

Tracing into the code, I've found that
DefaultExchangeStrategiesBuilder  is null.

Does anyone have any idea what is missing?
It's a simple web client.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it related to the webclient is initialized in quartz job scheduler's  at ..............CollectorJob.execute(CollectorJob.java:35)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Adding these dependencies and making sure the versions are the same.
I only had jackson-core before.

I tried to move the job out of quartz and ran it directly in main.
it still threw an exception, but it's different and  I then looked it up
and some one has asked the issue and the solution to make sure both jackson packages need to be included and versions must be same.

I then added them to the pom file. try to run the job and it worked.
Putting the job back to quartz to run and it also worked.